# Not able to execute a fileupload program in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, single-page-application

I have a simple program that I am trying to execute from online tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm but I am getting an exception as follows:

I am relatively new to nodejs and any sort of help or guidance will be much appreciated.

**Using NodeJS version: 4.1.1.**

**Exception**

```
TypeError: app.use() requires middleware functions
    at EventEmitter.use (c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:209:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (c:\nital\my-data\my-sample-apps\nodejs\tutorialspoint-samples\Sample37.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:452:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:475:10)
    at startup (node.js:117:18)
    at node.js:951:3
```

**FileUploadDemo.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(multer({dest: 'C:/tmp/'}));

app.get('/upload.html', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/" + "upload.html");
});

//uploading the file here
app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
    console.log(req.files.file.name);
    console.log(req.files.file.path);
    console.log(req.files.file.type);

    var file = __dirname + "/" + req.files.file.name;
    fs.readFile(req.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                response = {
                    message: 'File uploaded successfully',
                    filename: req.files.file.name
                };
            }
            console.log(response);
            res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
        });
    });
});

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the api of multer has changed. Since the tutorial uses `npm install multer --save` it pulls in the latest version rather than making sure the version you have is compatible. Details on how to use it can be found on the [npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer). It seems you now need to add the particular middleware you want into the specific route:

```
// Remove this line: app.use(multer({dest: 'C:/tmp/'}));
// Put this in instead
var upload = multer({ dest: 'C:/tmp/' });

// Change this: app.post('/file_upload', function (req, res) {
// to
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function (req, res) {
```

Though you could probably still use `app.use` to add it to all routes, you definitely need to change it to use upload.single (or another of their choice of middlewares).

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code which I compare the different from the nodejs tutorial.

**server.js**

```
//20160720 tested!
//[dif]:= different from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/nodejs/nodejs_express_framework.htm

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require("fs");

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//[dif]app.use(multer({ dest: '/tmp/'}));
var upload = multer({ dest: '/tmp/'}); 


app.get('/index.htm', function (request, response) {response.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.htm" );})

//[dif]app.post('/file_upload', function (request, response) {
app.post('/file_upload', upload.single('file'), function (request, response) {

/*[dif]
   console.log(request.files.file.name);
   console.log(request.files.file.path);
   console.log(request.files.file.type);
   var file = __dirname + "/" + request.files.file.name;
   fs.readFile( request.files.file.path, function (err, data) {
[dif]*/
   console.log(request.file.originalname);
   console.log(request.file.path);
   console.log(request.file.mimetype);


//[dif]   var file = __dirname + "/" + request.file.name;
   var file = __dirname + "/" + request.file.originalname;

   fs.readFile( request.file.path, function (err, data) {

        fs.writeFile(file, data, function (err) {
         if( err ){
              console.log( err );
         }else{
               uploadResponse = {
                   message:'File uploaded successfully',
//[dif]                   filename:request.files.file.name
                   filename:request.file.originalname

              };
          }
          console.log( uploadResponse );
          response.end( JSON.stringify( uploadResponse ) );
       });
   });
})

var server = app.listen(8081, function () {
  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
})
```

If you get the error - "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\tmp\ce194372b624b45f2c881140fecad07f'
    at Error (native)"
You should create the tmp folder in your root path for save temporary files.
in my case is "c:\tmp", and the "ce194372b624b45f2c881140fecad07f" is the tmporary file. you should delete it after file uploaded successfully.

Comment: just to be clear the original problem was that  "app.use(multer({ dest: '/tmp/'}))" line, and you also provided all remaining changes to make the code work, right?